# OpenVPN + DNScrypt

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, openvpn

I'm using Debian 7 Wheezy. I've installed OpenVPN using this awesome, fully automated script:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/cwaffles/ezopenvpn/master/ezopenvpn.sh --no-check-certificate -O ezopenvpn.sh
chmod +x ezopenvpn.sh
./ezopenvpn.sh
```

Then I've installed DNScrypt using this awesome, fully automated script:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/simonclausen/dnscrypt-autoinstall/master/dnscrypt-autoinstall.sh --no-check-certificate
chmod +x dnscrypt-autoinstall.sh
./dnscrypt-autoinstall.sh
```

OpenVPN as server and client works. DNScrypt works but on the node server, not on OpenVPN client.

The question is: how to configure server to get DNS from DNScrypt while I'm connected to OpenVPN?

Comment: Be careful executing arbitrary shell commands on scripts you download from the internet. At the bare minimum, read the .sh script before executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push DNS server IP in your OpenVPN configuration to the clients:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.0.2.53"
```

Of course, replace 192.0.2.53 with the actual IP of your DNS server.

Comment: Awesome, it works. DNS addresses taken from /etc/resolv.conf and pushed them to /etc/openvpn/server.conf. It was 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 as they have been created by script. Thank you Teun!

Comment: And how would you do it on Windows 7?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but I don't think it would be any different with OpenVPN on Windows.